# How do I set an Electron variable at compile time?

Tags: webpack, electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder to package a React app. My app uses the create-react-app boilerplate.

Is there a way I can set a variable at compile time, so that it can be used in a conditional within the code in the main process at runtime...?

I'm looking for an equivalent to C's preprocessor macros. So I could do something like:

`electron-builder --extraConfig BUILD_TYPE=testing`

Then in my main.js:

`if (extraConfig.BUILD_TYPE === 'testing') { // do stuff }`

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before but I'm using `electron-webpack` in addition to what you already have:

```
electron ^11.2.0
electron-builder ^22.9.1
electron-webpack ^2.8.2
webpack ^4
```

The idea is to expose a variable via `webpack.DefinePlugin` and you can do this for both your main and renderer processes.

With `electron-webpack` you can provide a `webpack` configuration for both processes:

```javascript
// webpack.main.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [ new webpack.DefinePlugin({__BURRITO__: true}) ]
};

// webpack.renderer.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [ new webpack.DefinePlugin({__TACO__: true}) ]
};
```

These two files are exposed to `electron-webpack` via a bit of configuration in `package.json`:

```json
{
  …
  "electronWebpack": {
    "main": {
      "webpackConfig": "webpack.main.config.js"
    },
    "renderer": {
      "webpackConfig": "webpack.renderer.config.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your main process:

```javascript
// src/main/index.js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}});
  console.log(__BURRITO__ ? "" : "");
  mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:${process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_WDS_PORT}`);
});
```

Two things:

1. The `.loadURL` bit looks funny but that's only because I'm using `electron-webpack` default html template for the renderer. During development it is served through this local server.
2. You shouldn't need to enable the `nodeIntegration` flag. That is only because `electron-webpack` default renderer template uses a few `require` statements here and there.

If your renderer process includes some scripts they'll have access to your *at-compile-time* variable too. Here again I'm leveraging `electron-webpack` default template which requires `src/renderer/index.js` automatically:

```javascript
// src/renderer/index.js
if (__TACO__) {
  document.body.innerHTML = ""
}
```

When you run this via `electron-webpack dev` then you can see two things:

1. A burrito is seen in the output of the main process
2. A taco is seen in the html of the renderer process

This shows that `electron-webpack` successfully injected two variables at compile time.

[image]

Comment: thanks! Are you using create-react-app...? If I follow the instructions above, I get an error `Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled` then `Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not but I'm definitely using React and Babel in the project I'm working on that uses that approach and it works fine. Setting Babel & React can be a long and frustrating journey though!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the `electron-builder` command in an NPM script, then run another script beforehand to set `BUILD_TYPE` in a `.txt` file.

Like this:

`package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "distProd": "node ./setBuildType.js prod && electron-builder",
    "distDev": "node ./setBuildType.js dev && electron-builder",
}
```

Then inside `setBuildType.js`:

```javascript
// process.argv[2] Contains the type.
fs.writeFile('./BUILD_TYPE.txt', process.argv[2], function (errObj) {
    if (errObj) {
        console.log(errObj);
    }
});
```

Then from your app, get `BUILD_TYPE` with:

```javascript
// Always set `BUILD_TYPE` to `dev` when running from the terminal.
if (!app.isPackaged) {
    var BUILD_TYPE = fs.readFileSync('./BUILD_TYPE.txt');
} else {
    var BUILD_TYPE = 'dev';
}
console.log(BUILD_TYPE); // Outputs "prod" or "dev".
```

That'll check if it's running from an installer or from the terminal, if it's running from the terminal then it'll always set `BUILD_TYPE` to `dev`.