# Ruby net/http/get does not work with url's, but works with uri's. Why?

Tags: ruby, http, get

I have a Ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798852/how-do-i-set-an-electron-variable-at-compile-time"
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url, '/')
```

Which produces errors:

```
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

and

```
Failed to open TCP connection to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798852/how-do-i-set-an-electron-variable-at-compile-time:80 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) (SocketError)
```

But it works perfectly with uri:

```
require 'net/http'
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798852/how-do-i-set-an-electron-variable-at-compile-time"
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

So, could anyone explain what is the difference, why it works so, and what is so special about URI?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response) mentions that `The target can either be specified as (uri), or as (host, path, port = 80)` So for first call to succeed it should have been `Net::HTTP.get_response('stackoverflow.com', '/questions/65798852/how-do-i-set-an-electron-variable-at-compile-time')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that your `url` is an instance of `String` which happens to be a URL. But because it is just a simple string is has no special meaning.

Whereas `uri` is an instance of [`URI`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html) which is not only a simple string but had the URL from the string already analyzed and it now offers several optimized methods to return specific parts of the URL – like the protocol, the hostname, the path or query parameters.